# Evaluate the following integral $ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\lbrace x\rbrace-\frac{1}2}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta, fractional-part

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\lbrace x\rbrace-\frac{1}2}{x} dx$$
Here $\lbrace\cdot\rbrace$ denotes the fractional part.

I found this challenging integral, and I'm curious about the solution, so I decided to do some efforts to solve it, but sadly I didn't, any hints?

**Attempts:**

\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\lbrace x\rbrace-\frac{1}2}{x} dx&=\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1\lbrace x\rbrace-1}{2x} dx\\
&=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\lbrace x\rbrace}{x}-\frac{1}{2x}dx\\
&=\int_1^\infty \frac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor-1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x}dx\\
&=\int_1^\infty \frac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor-1}{x} dx -\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{2x}
\end{align}
I thought about this property:
$$\int_0^\infty \varphi (x) dx=\lim_{a\to \infty} \int_0^a \varphi(x) dx$$
So I applied it only for the second fraction because its antiderivative was easy enough, and here's what I've got:
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{2x}&=\lim_{a\to \infty} \int_1^a \frac{dx}{2x}\\
&=\lim_{a\to \infty}\frac{\ln (x)}{2}\bigg\vert_0^a\\
&=\lim_{a\to \infty}\frac{\ln (a)}2 -\frac{\ln (0)}{2}
\end{align}
And here I felt that I'm wrong I can't get $\infty -\infty$, So any thoughts or hints, I'll be thankfull!

Comment: $\int dx/x$ is divergent, what is important is $\{x\}-1/2$ change sign, so it ressembles $\sum (-1)^n/n$. You should try $\sum u_n$ where $u_n=\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx=\int_n^{n+1/2}+\int_{n+1/2}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Sure I'll try, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sorry, I'll edit it right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to take away from @Whatsup's clever answer, but I did it another way.

Start with the integral formula, valid for $\Re(s)>0$:
$$
\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} - s\int _1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x^{s+1}}\,dx
$$Introduce the $1/2$ in the integrand:
$$
\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} - s\int _1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}-1/2+1/2}{x^{s+1}}\,dx
$$$$
\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} - s\int _1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}-1/2}{x^{s+1}}\,dx - \frac{1}{2}
$$Solve for the integral:
$$
\int _1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}-1/2}{x^{s+1}}\,dx = \frac{-2 (s-1) \zeta (s)+s+1}{2 (s-1) s}
$$Take the limit as $s\to 0^+$; the LHS exists by Dirichlet's Test and the RHS can be evaluated using L'Hôpital's Rule.
$$
\int _1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}-1/2}{x}\,dx =\lim_{s\to 0^+} \frac{-2 (s-1) \zeta (s)+s+1}{2 (s-1) s}
$$
$$
=\lim_{s\to 0^+} \frac{-2 (s-1) \zeta '(s)-2 \zeta (s)+1}{4s-2}
$$Using $\zeta(0)=-1/2$ and $\zeta'(0)=-1/2\log(2 \pi)$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3706413) gives the same result.
$$
=\lim_{s\to 0^+} \frac{-2 (s-1) (-1/2\log(2 \pi))-2 (-1/2)+1}{4s-2}
$$
$$
=1/2\log(2 \pi)-1= \log(\sqrt{2\pi}/e)
$$

Comment: Ohh, Nice approach! thank you for the intuitive solution (+1) from me!

Comment: Of course, my pleasure.

Comment: You deserve the correct answer, I'm really fascinated by your answer!

Comment: It needs to be proved that
$$\lim_{s \to 0^+} \int_1^\infty \frac {\{x\} - \frac 1 2} {x^{s + 1}} dx =
\int_1^\infty \frac {\{x\} - \frac 1 2} x dx,$$
the existence of the rhs is not a sufficient condition for that.

Comment: @Maxim Dirichlet's Test works here; the integral of numerator is uniformly bounded and $1/x$ is monotonic and decreasing to zero.

Comment: It proves that the integral on the rhs exists. It doesn't prove that the integral and the limit on the lhs can be interchanged, that is, that the integral on the lhs not only exists on $[0, \infty)$ but is also continuous from the right at $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. The integral on the left is clearly a continuous function of $s$ that exists for $s\in (0,\infty)$; in fact, it is increasing on $(0,1)$. You grant the existence of the integral on the right, which is the case $s=0$. So the LHS is uniformly continuous in $s$ on $[0,1]$, which should do it.

Comment: Where does the continuity (let alone uniform continuity) follow from? If
$$f(s, x) = \frac {[0 < x < s]} s + s,$$
then
$$\lim_{s \to 0^+} \int_0^1 f(s, x) dx \neq
\int_0^1 \lim_{s \to 0^+} f(s, x) dx$$
even though both the lhs and the rhs exist and $\int_0^1 f(s, x) dx$ is continuous and increasing on $(0, 1)$. So there have to be some additional conditions on the integrand, which haven't been stated.

Answer (score 10):

This function is not integrable in the Lebesgue sense, so you can only evaluate the Cauchy principal value.

That is, what you want to evaluate is the limit $$\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty} \int_1^M \frac{\{x\}-\frac12}xdx.$$

It is easy to see that it suffices to take the limit for integer values of $M$. We first compute, for every positive integer $k$:
$$\int_k^{k + 1}\frac{\{x\}-\frac12}xdx = \int_k^{k + 1}\frac{x- k-\frac12}xdx = 1 - \left(k + \frac 1 2\right) (\ln(k + 1) - \ln k).$$

We then take the sum:
$$\int_1^{M + 1} \frac{\{x\}-\frac12}xdx = \sum_{k = 1}^M\left(1 - \left(k + \frac 1 2\right) (\ln(k + 1) - \ln k)\right).$$

This simplifies to: $$M - \left(M + \frac12\right)\ln(M + 1) + \ln M!$$ which, by Stirling's formula, converges to $\ln\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}e\approx-0.0810614668$.

Comment: Nicely done!  I couldn't figure out how to evaluate the sum there.

Comment: thanks for your brilliant answer, I just don't get why isn't integrable as you said in the Lebesgue sense?

Comment: If a function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, then it is absolutely integrable, i.e. the function $|f|$ is also integrable. This is obviously not the case here.

Comment: @WhatsUp Okay, I got it now! Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: This isn't a Cauchy principal value. It's just an improper integral.

Comment: For completeness, it can be shown that the improper integral $I$ exists by applying Dirichlet's test. Then the limit of $\int_1^{a_M}$ over any sequence $a_M \to \infty$ is $I$.

Answer (score 0):

Euler-Maclaurin formula applied to $\log N!$ gives

$$
\begin{aligned}
\log N!
&=\int_1^N\log x\mathrm dx+{\log N\over2}+\int_1^N{\overline B_1(x)\over x}\mathrm dx \\
&=\left(N+\frac12\right)\log N-N+1+\int_1^N{\overline B_1(x)\over x}\mathrm dx
\end{aligned}
$$

However, according to Stirling's approximation, we have

$$
\log N!=\left(N+\frac12\right)\log N-N+\frac12\log2\pi+\mathcal O\left(\frac1N\right)
$$

Consequently as $N\to\infty$ we get

$$
\int_1^\infty{\overline B_1(x)\over x}\mathrm dx=\int_1^\infty{\{x\}-1/2\over x}\mathrm dx=-1+\frac12\log2\pi
$$