# Fractional part of a real number: questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractional-part

I was reading this question [Evaluate the following integral $ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\lbrace x\rbrace-\frac{1}2}{x} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769948/evaluate-the-following-integral-int-1-infty-frac-lbrace-x-rbrace-frac1) and I have seen that the user have used the **mantissa of a real number** or the **fractional part**.

I know that the mantissa of $x\in\Bbb R$ is defined by $\text{mant}(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $0\leq \text{mant}(x)<1$. I add the different symbologies.

$$\text{mant}(x)=\begin{cases}
\{x\}& \\
\text{frac}(x) &\\
M(x)
\end{cases}
$$

1. the mantissa of a real number is connected to the logarithms and in what way?
2. If I have $x=-0.43$, $\text{mant}(x)= -0.43-\lfloor (-0.43)\rfloor=\color{red}{ -0.43-(-1)\cdot \lfloor(+0.43)\rfloor}$? i.e. can I bring out the minus sign from if $x\in\Bbb R$, $\lfloor (-x)\rfloor \iff -\lfloor x\rfloor$? Is there a specific property?
3. What is the relevance of this mantissa function?

Comment: You are making it too complicated.  There is *always* a *unique integer $n$ so that $n \le x  < n+1$.  That number is $\lfloor x\rfloor$.  And there is always a unique $r: 0 \le r < ,1$ so that $n \le n+r = x \le n+1$ And (equivalently: $r=x-n$.   So if $x = -0.43$ then $-1 \le x < 0$ so $n=\lfloor -0.43\rfloor = -1$.  And we need $-1 + r = x=-0.43$   We solve for $r$ and get $r =-0.43-(-1) = -0.43+1 = 0.57$.  And indeed $-0.43 = -1 + 0.57$.  ... That's all.

Comment: @fleablood In the meantime, thank you very much. I ask you a kindness, if it were possible, to turn the comment into an answer with the other indications. I often do not read the comments and prefer to have everything in the answer.

Comment: $\text{mant}(x)= -0.43-\lfloor (-0.43)\rfloor\ne \color{red}{ -0.43-(-1)\cdot \lfloor(+0.43)\rfloor}$.  That is wrong! $\color{red}{ -0.43-(-1)\cdot \color{blue}{\lfloor(+0.43)\rfloor}= - 043-(-1)\cdot\color{blue}0=-0.43}$.  So not true.  But....$[x] + \{x\} = x$ *ALWAYS*.  So $\{x\} = x - [x]$ always.  And because $-1 \le -0.43 < 0$ we have $[-0.43] = -1$ and so we have $-1 +\{x\} = -0.43$ or $\{x\} = -0.43 - (-1)= -0.43 - [-0.43]$.

Comment: Also $[-x] \ne -[x]$.

Comment: @fleablood  Unfortunately, as the years go by, I'm forgetting everything. In high school where I teach these subjects cannot be dealt with. I hope you can convert your comments into a single answer. Thank you if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer, there is much more to say about this topic.

$2$: You can bring a minus outside of a floor, but when you do this, the floor becomes a ceiling.  In other words,
$$
\lfloor -0.43\rfloor = -1
$$
since the floor function means to round down.  On the other hand,
$$
\lfloor -0.43\rfloor = -\lceil 0.43\rceil=-1.
$$
Note that the fractional part of a negative number is sometimes defined in other ways (such as rounding towards zero).

$1$ and $3$: One big application of the mantissa is in how numbers are stored on a computer.  There are various ways to do this (and tricks which I am omitting).  But, a number is stored as a mantissa $m$ and an exponent $e$.  From this pair, the corresponding number is $m2^e$ (on a real computer the representation is slightly different, but I'm just trying to go for the idea).  This also shows where logarithms come into play, the exponent $e$ is a (rounded) logarithm of the desired number.

Example (using base $10$, instead of base $2$, which a computer would use): The number $1,578$ could be written as
$$
0.1578\cdot 10^4.
$$
The $0.1578$ would be the mantissa and the $4$ is the exponent.  Note that $4\leq\log_{10}1578<5$, a connection to logarithms.

Aside: On a real computer, the representation could be closer to
$$
1.578\cdot 10^3,
$$
where only the mantissa $0.578$ would be stored (on a computer, there is only one leading digit since binary has only numbers, $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much also to you. I not remember because $\lfloor -p\rfloor = -\lceil p\rceil$ . I have forgotten many properties. Unfortunately, these topics cannot be discussed in high school over the years. I have not understood $m2^e$. Can, please, to have some examples? Thank you again.

Comment: It's just a matter of if $n \le x < n+1$ then $-(n+1) < -x \le x$.  Not it *matter* if $x$ is an integer or not.  If $x$ is *not* and integer then $n < x < n+1$ and $n=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $n+1 = \lceil x \rceil$.  Ceilings round up, floors round down.  When you the negative they get reversed.  $\lfloor x\rfloor =n < x < n+1 = \lceil x\rceil$ so $\lfloor -x\rfloor =-(n+1)=-\lceil x\rceil < -x < -n = -\lfloor x\rfloor=\lceil -x\rceil$.  .... And if $x$ is an integer then we just have $x=\lfloor x\rfloor=\lceil x\rceil$ and $-x=-\lfloor x\rfloor=-\lceil x\rceil$.