# Why is $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \{x\} =1$

Tags: limits

Graphically, it’s pretty clear, since the graph before $x=0$ tends to 1. But I am not able to understand it intuitively. How exactly is $\{-0.0000005\} =1$ when it should be $0.000005$?

Comment: How do you define $\{x\}?$

Comment: This depends on your definition of $\{x\}$. Typically it's defined by $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ in which case clearly$$\{-0.005\}=-0.005-(-1)=0.995$$for example

Comment: @PeterForeman You're right. There is also a my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770328/fractional-part-of-a-real-number-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{x\}$ is usually (and in this instance specifically) $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, with $\lfloor x\rfloor=\max\{n\in\Bbb Z\,:\, n\le x\}$. Therefore, $\lfloor x\rfloor=-1$ for all $x\in[-1,0)$ and so on.

On the other hand, you appear to be speculating on different notion which does not apply to the text you are reading: in terms of the first one, yours would be $d(x)=\{\lvert x\rvert\}$

Comment: Okay, but isn’t the fractional part of $x$ in this case $0.00005$?

Comment: I have already stated my mind about what I believe your textbook means and what you mean instead. It's not like asking again will result in a different answer.