# How to prove $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln \left (\Gamma(x) \right) \,dx = -{\zeta'}(0)$?

Tags: calculus, riemann-zeta

How do you prove $$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln \left (\Gamma(x) \right) \,dx = -{\zeta'}(0)$$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann Zeta function.

Comment: The natural way is to prove first the Weierstrass product for $\Gamma(s)$ then to integrate termwise being careful with the convergence and the analytic continuation stuff.

Comment: Maybe prove separately $\int_0^1\ln(\Gamma(x))\,dx = \ln(1/\sqrt{2\pi})$ and $\zeta'(0)=\ln\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\begin{align*} 
   2\int_{0}^{1} \ln \Gamma(x) \mathrm{d} x&=\int_{0}^{1} \ln \Gamma(x) \mathrm{d} x+ \int_{0}^{1} \ln \Gamma(1-x) \mathrm{d} x\\[1ex]
    &=\int_{0}^{1} \ln (\Gamma(x) \Gamma(1-x)) \mathrm{d} x \\[1ex]
&=\int_{0}^{1} \ln (2 \pi) \mathrm{d} x-\int_{0}^{1} \ln (2 \sin (\pi x)) \mathrm{d} x \\[1ex]
&=\ln (2 \pi). 
\end{align*}$$ The last step follows from equality $$\begin{equation*}
    -\ln (2 \sin (\pi x))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cos (2 n \pi x) 
\end{equation*}$$ end the fact you can interchange order of sum with integral. At the end it suffices to use [Particular values of the Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Derivatives) or [Computing the value of $\zeta'(0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706413/computing-the-value-of-zeta0?noredirect=1) if you wish to calculate zerta part also.